# Pass an object as part of ng-map marker

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

Using markers in `ng-map` with angular JS

```
<ng-map zoom-to-include-markers="auto" default-style="false" class="myMap">
    <marker ng-repeat="Customer in ListForDisplay"  position="{{Customer.location.lat}},{{Customer.location.lng}}" icon="{{Customer.icon}}" clickedaddress="{{Customer.address}}" clickedextras="{{Customer.extrasString}}" data="{{Customer}}"  on-click="markerSingleClick($event)" on-dblclick="markerDoubleClick($event)"></marker>
</ng-map>
```

I can access the string variables in the controller, but the object *data*  still stays undefined in debugging sessions:

```
$scope.markerSingleClick = function (event) {
     var clickedaddress = this.clickedaddress;
     var clickedextras = this.clickedextras;
     var data = this.data;
```

Is there a way to pass an entire object as part of the marker, rather than single string properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass current object as a parameter via marker `on-click` event, replace

```
on-click="markerSingleClick($event)"
```

with

```
on-click="markerSingleClick({{Customer}})"
```

and then update `markerSingleClick` function:

```
$scope.markerSingleClick= function (event,customer) {
    //...          
};
```

**Working example**

```js
angular.module('mapApp', ['ngMap'])
    .controller('mapCtrl', function ($scope, NgMap) {


        NgMap.getMap().then(function (map) {
            $scope.map = map;
        });
        $scope.cities = [
            { id: 1, name: 'Oslo', pos: [59.923043, 10.752839] },
            { id: 2, name: 'Stockholm', pos: [59.339025, 18.065818] },
            { id: 3, name: 'Copenhagen', pos: [55.675507, 12.574227] },
            { id: 4, name: 'Berlin', pos: [52.521248, 13.399038] },
            { id: 5, name: 'Paris', pos: [48.856127, 2.346525] }
        ];

        $scope.showInfo = function (event,city) {
              alert(JSON.stringify(city));
              //console.log(city);
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script> 
<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
        <ng-map zoom="5" center="59.339025, 18.065818">            
            <marker ng-repeat="c in cities" position="{{c.pos}}" title="{{c.name}}" id="{{c.id}}" on-click="showInfo({{c}})">
            </marker>
        </ng-map>
    </div>
```

---

Another option would be to pass object *identifier* as a parameter, for example its index:

```
<marker ng-repeat="c in cities" on-click="showInfo($index)" position="{{c.pos}}" title="{{c.name}}" id="{{c.id}}">
</marker>
```

Then current object could be determined like this:

```
$scope.showInfo = function (event,index) {
     var currentCity = $scope.cities[index]; 
     //console.log(currentCity);
};
```